# Degree of $F(x+y)$ over $F=k(x^3,y^3)$ in characteristic $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $k$ be a field and let $x$ and $y$ be indeterminates. Consider $F=k(x^3,y^3)$. One can easily show that $F(x+y)$ is a degree $3$ extension of $F$ when $k$ has characteristic $3$. I was also able to show that $F(x+y)=F(x,y)$, a degree $9$ extension, when the characteristic of $k$ is neither $2$ nor $3$ by expressing $x$ and $y$ as rational functions in terms of $x+y$ with coefficients in $F$. But my expression required dividing by $2$ (and $3$), so I am left to wonder

> what is the degree of $F(x+y)$ over $F=k(x^3,y^3)$ when $k$ has characteristic $2$?

Edit: For those curious, here was how I wrote $x$ and $y$ as a rational function of $x+y$ over $F$:

First, we may express $x-y$ as
$$x-y=\frac{(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}=\frac{x^3-y^3}{(x+y)^2-\frac{(x+y)^3-x^3-y^3}{3(x+y)}}\in F(x+y).$$

Once we have both $x+y$ and $x-y$, we can write
$$x=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)+\frac{1}{2}(x-y),$$
$$y=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)-\frac{1}{2}(x-y).$$
But of course, you can see how these last expressions don't work in characteristic $2$. Thank you to Jyrki Lahtonen for commenting a solution that works even in characteristic $2$!

Comment: If we assume that $k$ contains a primitive third root of unity $\omega$, then $L=k(x,y)$ is Galois over $F$ with Galois group isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3$, $x\mapsto \omega^ix, y\mapsto \omega^j y$, $i$ and $j$ independent parameters from $\{0,1,2\}$. The conjugates of $x+y$ are thus $\omega^ix+\omega^jy$. Clearly all distinct, so the minimal polynomial still has degree nine. I can't see how the possible need to adjoin $\omega$ to $k$ would change anything.

Comment: A bit roundabout way could be to observe that (still in characteristic two)
$$xy=\frac{x^2y+xy^2}{x+y}=\frac{(x+y)^3-x^3-y^3}{x+y}$$
Is an element of $K=F(x+y)$. Therefore $x$ and $y$ are the zeros of the polynomial
$$p(T)=(T-x)(T-y)=T^2-(x+y)T+xy\in K[T].$$
As $p(T)$ is quadratic, we can conclude that $[F(x,y):K]\le2$. But $[F[x,y):F]=9$ is odd, so the only option is $K=F(x,y)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ohhh that's brilliant! I was able to get that $xy\in F(x+y)$ but didn't make the connection that $x$ and $y$ are thus solutions to a quadratic over $F(x+y)$. Thanks!

Comment: Good! Feel free to post all the calculations as an aswer (for more feedback and also to get the question wrapped up). I'm actually a bit curious to see how you write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $(x+y)$, $x^3$ and $y^3$. Even if it works only when $6\cdot 1_k\neq 0_k$ :-) May be somebody can then find a way to make that approach work in characteristic two as well?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I just edited my post to include the expression I derived. You can see my method was to obtain $x-y$ and then write $x$ as the average of $x+y$ and $x-y$, and analogously for $y$. If I have time, I'll post an answer based on your observation. Thanks again!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  If we put $s=x+y,a=x^3,b=y^3$, then the identity 
$x=\frac{2s^7-7(a+b)s^4 + (5b^2 - 35ab + 14a^2)s}{9(a^2-b^2)}$ holds in any characteristic not equal to $3$ (in particular it holds in characteristic $2$), but it seems hard to derive that identity in a natural manner.

Answer (score 1):

$F(x,y)/F$ is separable of degree $9$

The $F$-conjugates of $x,y$ are $\zeta_3^n x,\zeta_3^m y$

So the $F$-conjugates of $x+y$ are $\zeta_3^n x+\zeta_3^m y$

$x+y$ has $9$-distinct $F$-conjugates so $[F(x+y):F]=9$.

Comment: Doesn't this solution require assuming $k$ contains $\zeta_3$?